# Keeping $_session['username'] inside a ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I've been messing with a script, and i'm now currently at the protection part.
Basically i cant manage to receive a `$_session['username']` request.
I can not use cookies, as these can be faked. And it's a pretty big security hole.
Is this a common issue?

(The non-ajax and ajax page have the same session-id, and yes. i do use session_start();)

If you know any good comment-scripts it would be appriciated if you would like to link! c: )

edit:
The user logs in, and the session is started.
Now i'm combining a page/post with a modified comment script. (found here: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/ )
What i've done is that i made it work with multiple pages, and removed the user & password thing that was provided with the script.

The request is something similar to this:

$user = $_session['username'];

if(!($data['user'] = $user)){
   $errors['error'] = $_session['username']; //just to see if it can find the username
}

The above request returns a null value, but if i run "echo $_session['username'];" on the page that calls java, i get "powback".

EDIT:
i couldn't get this to work, but i made a bypass. I managed to insert $_session['username'] directly into the database with an other kind of validation. The current one was stupid... It should work properly now. Thank you!

Comment: Sessions are stored on the server. Are you trying to verify that the source of the Ajax request is the same as whatever non-Ajax source triggered the creation of the session (say, as part of an authentication routine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   var v="any variable to be passed";
     $.post( "passingfile.php",{name:v}, 
     function(data) {
        Alert("Pass OK");
     });
     return false; 

  });
```

If you for the security try not to pass session id via url

Answer (score 1):

How are you passing the session ID if not via a cookie? If you're passing it via URL (which is an even bigger security risk), make sure you pass it in the URL of your AJAX request.

Comment: I'm passing the session via a cookie, but the authentication routine is basically confirming that a post value that contains the username is the same as $_session['username']. However, i can't retrieve the session value inside the ajax. On the non-ajax source it's possible to retrieve it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this inside any function or document ready. and change page name where you want to post value.

```
var postRecord = 'variable='+value;
$.post("PHP_Page_Where_you_are_using_session.php", postRecord,  function(response,status, xhr){
                        if (status == "success") {
                            alert('done');
                        }
                        else if (status == "error") {
                            alert('Something went wrong, we are working to fix it'); 
                        }
});
```

on another page you can get post value within $_POST['variable'];

change name of variable to another one that you want to use.